# Trying to add onesignal notification in ionic 6 but getting error

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal

Native: tried calling OneSignal.getIds, but the OneSignal plugin is not installed.
Install the OneSignal plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin'
while it already installed .
Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.8
Ionic Framework               : not installed
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 15.2.6
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 15.2.6
@angular/cli                  : 15.2.6
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 9.0.0
Cordova:
Cordova CLI       : 11.1.0
Cordova Platforms : android 10.1.2
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 4 other plugins)
Utility:
cordova-res : 0.15.4
native-run  : 1.7.1
System:
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
NodeJS            : v14.21.2
npm               : 6.14.17
OS                : Windows 10

Comment: if you are using capacitor, check here https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-setup